# Add onclick function to input

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, input

I want to add a js function to an input field located in a phtml page 
on my magento 2 I have write my function like below:

```
<script>
     function qtyzn() {
         .....               
      }
</script>
```

and my input is:
`<input  oninput="qtyzn();" value="1" id="nbrbox" />`

I dont really get how to make this work on my magento 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery events like below method will work

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'],function($){
      jQuery('#nbrbox').on('input', function(){
           var nbrbox = document.getElementById('nbrbox').value;
           var qtybox = parseFloat(document.getElementById('qtybox').textContent);
           var qtysquare =(Math.round(nbrbox*qtybox*100))/100;

           document.getElementById('qtysquare').innerHTML = qtysquare;
           document.getElementById('qtysquare').value = qtysquare;
           var nbrsqaure = (Math.round(nbrbox*qtybox*100))/100;
           document.getElementById('nbrsqaure').innerHTML = nbrsqaure;
           document.getElementById('nbrsqaure').value = nbrsqaure;
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where I put this code please!

Comment: You can put this code in phtml file.....or if you need this code in multiple pages you need to enqueue custom.js and put js code only in that file. Hope you aware of how to enqueue custom.js.

Comment: thank you, this what im looking for

Comment: You're welcome...